# Автопереход на другую страницу

Tags: android

Есть `EditText`. После того, как длина строки в нем станет равной 4 символам, автоматически перейти на другую `Activity`

Comment: Поставьте слушатель на EditText https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать слушатели для `EditText`. Для примера [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher). Пример кодa:

```
    private static int START_ACTIVITY_SYMBOL_SIZE = 4
    ...
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if(s.length() == START_ACTIVITY_SYMBOL_SIZE){
            startYourActivity();
          }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```